# Installing Drush - permission denied error

Tags: drush

I just successfully installed Drush user composer into the .composer/vendor/bin folder.  When I try to run "drush status" I get an error 
sh: /Users/Marianna/drush: Permission denied

What do I do now?

Comment: `chmod u+x /Users/Marianna/drush` ?

Comment: Ambiguous. /Users/Marianna/drush should not exist if the installation method was composer. If this was a git install, then this folder would be a directory, not the executable. Please double-check your installation steps against the docs: http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/

Comment: @greg_1_anderson I guess @MG1 forget adding `global` when he runs composer.

Comment: @greg_1_anderson I did follow the steps of installing drush with composer by doing "composer global require drush/drush" what's the fix?

Comment: Are you using MAMP?

Comment: yes - I'm using MAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow following two links, they are simple two steps and make the Drush running perfectly with no issue, even you can upgrade drush with that.

(1) [How to install the Drush using Homebrew](http://ionemind.com/content/installing-drush-mac-using-homebrew). And after that follow following steps to Symlink the php file location between your servers and MAMP.

(2) [MAMP: Symlink PHP to /usr/bin/php](http://blog.rickbuczynski.com/)

I was facing the same issue and re-installed using above steps and this set of two links worked perfectly.

Comment: Ok - so creating the link fixed the error from showing up.  But now I see that running "drush en zurb_foundation" doesn't do anything at all...

Comment: What error it is showing?

Comment: No errors at all  sh-3.2# drush en zurb_foundation
sh-3.2#

Comment: run "drush cc all", Is it working without error?

Comment: Did you check path before running those two commands? Paths may not be same what shown on page, that is from that author's system, your may be different.

Comment: Yes I matched them to my phpinfo(); settings: when I run php -i | grep ini results: Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/conf
Loaded Configuration File => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/conf/php.ini  And from the phpinfo file: Configuration File (php.ini) Path /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.29/conf
Loaded Configuration File /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42885/discussion-between-codenext-and-mg1).

Comment: Hey, did you problem solved? I suggest you try both steps, and complete entire process.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing drush from the User folder.