# How to fix my problem when trying to create a Drupal sub-theme with Drush?

Tags: 7, theming, drush

I get the following error when I try to run the "drush fst foundation-subtheme" command.

```
sh-3.2# drush fst foundation-subtheme
The drush command 'fst foundation-subtheme' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush`  [error]
to clear the commandfile cache if you have installed new extensions.
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                    [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this
case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with
the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have
no access to it in a jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.
```

Drush was attempting to connect to:

> Drupal version         :  7.32
>   Site URI               :  http://default
>
> Database driver        :  mysql
>   Database hostname      :  localhost
>   Database port          :  3306
>   Database username      :  root
>   Database name          :  drupal
>   PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
>   PHP configuration      :
>   PHP OS                 :  Darwin
>   Drush script           : 
>   /Users/Marianna/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php   Drush version
>   :  8.1.3                                                    Drush temp
>   directory   :  /tmp
>   Drush configuration    :
>   Drush alias files      :
>   Drupal root            :  /Users/Marianna/Documents/Sites/Link-New
>   Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php
>   Site path              :  sites/default

I get the following error when I try to install foundation with drush:

```
sh-3.2# drush --uri=http://linkengineering en zurb_foundation
Command pm-enable needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a  [error]
more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
The drush command 'en zurb_foundation' could not be executed.                                   [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                                    [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this
case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with
the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have
no access to it in a jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.
```

Drush was attempting to connect to:

> Drupal version         :  7.32
>   Site URI               :  http://linkengineering
>   Database driver        :  mysql
>   Database hostname      :  localhost
>   Database port          :  3306
>   Database username      :  root
>   Database name          :  drupal
>   PHP executable         :  /usr/bin/php
>   PHP configuration      :
>   PHP OS                 :  Darwin
>   Drush script           : 
>   /Users/Marianna/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php   Drush version
>   :  8.1.3                                                    Drush temp
>   directory   :  /tmp
>   Drush configuration    :
>   Drush alias files      :
>   Drupal root            :  /Users/Marianna/Documents/Sites/Link-New
>   Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php
>   Site path              :  sites/default

Comment: Per the instructions, you successfully ran `drush en zurb_foundation; drush cc all` prior to running the `drush fst` command yes?

Comment: No - I installed foundation manually.. Should I go back and do it this way?

Comment: I edited my question about with the error that I get when running drush en

Comment: Both errors seem to point to the same problem - you're not running `drush` from a Drupal environment. Does the file `/Users/Marianna/Documents/Sites/Link-New/index.php` exist?

Comment: yes - that file exists

Comment: You can follow the answer which I have given to your previous question, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207881/installing-drush-permission-denied-error/207996#207996. That will solve the issue of Drupal environment and php.

Comment: Is this suggesting to reinstall Drush?  when I do drush status - I don't get any errors.  Is it possible to fix this without reinstalling?

Comment: Yes you can skip the first step if you have already installed. Go for second step, that is important to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you try to change Database hostname to 127.0.0.1 and then have a look?

Comment: Creating the link to the correct php worked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue mostly will be with environment/php and this is issue with MAMP (mismatch of path your MAMP-php and Server-php). Follow this [link](http://blog.rickbuczynski.com/) from that article.

> The Solution: A Symlink
>
> For the sake of ease, let’s just make your terminal sessions use the
>   same PHP executable as MAMP. So run this:
>
> ```
> $ mv /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php.bak 
> $ ln -s /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/bin/php /usr/bin/php
> ```

But you need to check path as per your folders.